# What is meant by the negative slope if isothermal process?

Tags: thermodynamics

We know that slope of isothermal curve is -P/V but what is the meaning of negative sign in that formula?

Comment: it means that at the same temperature if you increase the gas volume you decrease the pressure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not said what graph you are plotting.
Perhaps you  mean, for an ideal gas, that
$$
\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T<0?
$$
This means that the volume decreases   as the pressure  increases.

From $PV= nRT$, we have that at fixed $T$
$$
0=d(PV)= VdP+PdV \quad \Rightarrow 
\frac {dV}{dP}= -\frac  V P,
$$
and, as both $P$ and $V$ are positive, the graph of $V$ against $P$ has a negative slope.

We also have that
$$
\left(\frac {\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T= -\frac    P V,
$$
so the graph of $P$ andainst $V$ also has a negative slope and  pressure  drops as the volume  increases.